Using three quaternions and times to derive quadratic constants?
Hi I am trying to derive the quadratic constants when given three quaternions and times. Given $q1,q2,q3,t1,t2,t3$ derive $a,b,c$ such that
$f(t1)=q1$
$f(t2)=q2$
$f(t3)=q3$
Lets assume we have a function $g(x)$ that converts a rotation vector to a quaternion. then we have $f(x)=g(ax2+bx)∗c$. I am trying to figure out how to calculate what $a,b,c$ need to be to satisfy the above constraints.
Note a and b will be in the form of rotational vectors, while c will be a quaternion.
...
so it would be applied by converting the result of $ax^2 + bx$ to a quaternion and multiplying with c.
so to test out my solutions I put together some sample constants for a, b and c and then evaluated at three different times.
Then would try to rederive a, b, and c from the results and times.
One approach I tried was converting the quaternions to rotation vectors and then did the normal approach to solving for a quadratic given three points and times.
Then would convert c back to a quaternion.
C would consistently be pretty close, but a and b would be really far off.
Then I had the idea of extending this by taking advantage that c seemed to be pretty consistent. I would take the inverse of c and make the rotations relative to c and then convert them back to rotation vectors ($v_0, v_1,v_2$).
I would then solve for a and b like so.
$s_0 = v_0/t_0$
$s_1 = v_1/t_1$
$a = (s_1 - s_0) / (t_1 - t_0)$
$b = (s_1 - a * t_1) * 2.0$
When using these in quadratic form and plugging $t_0, t_1, and t_1$ back in the results would mostly be close and sometimes super far off.
This feels unreliable as a solution. Is there a better approach for this?

It is not clear to me at all what you're talking about or asking for. So $a,b,c$ are quaternions? And $x$ is a scalar? Are you saying you want to solve the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for $x$?

$a$ and $b$ be would be vectors ($axis * angle$) and $c$ would be a quaternion.
x would be a scalar.
The goal is determine what $a$, $b$, and $c$ should be such that when passing in the original times for $x$, the corresponding quaternions used to derive $a$, $b$, and $c$ are produced.

So you're treating vectors $a,b$　as imaginary quaternions? And you're saying that you have three values $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that you want $f(x_1),f(x_2),f(x_3)$ to be quaternions that "derive" $a,b,c$? What does it mean for quaternions to "derive" $a,b,c$?

The other way.
Given $q_1, q_2, q_3, t_1, t_2, t_3$ derive $a, b, c$ such that
$f(t_1) = q_1$
$f(t_2) = q_2$
$f(t_3) = q_3$
lets assume we have a function g(x) that converts a rotation vector to a quaternion.
then $f(x)=g(ax^2 + bx) * c$.
I am trying to figure out how to calculate what $a,b,c$ need to be to satisify the above constraints.

The solution for calculating a, b, and c in my initial question gives me relatively accurate answers most of the time. For my testing I randomize a,b,c and t1,t2,t3 and calculate f(t1), f(t2), f(t3). Then store the results of f(t1) as q1, f(t1) as q2, f(t3) as q3.
I'll then go through the steps in my initial question to solve for a, b, and c.
Then to see if the recalculated a, b, and c are correct I will then evaluate f(t1), f(t2), f(t3) using the recalculated a, b, and c. if the results equal the original q1, q2, and q3 then it worked. sometimes it's really far (0.045% attempts are bad).

"The other way. Given..." <-- This comment should be the content of your question. That also is not the $f(x)$ you wrote previously.

updated the question accordingly. Thank you for the feedback.

If $a,b$ are represented as unit quaternions, then $g$ is the exponential function and $f(x) = e^{ax^2+bx}c$. Thus, if one of $t_1,t_2,t_3$ is $0$ then you know $c = f(0)$. Let's say $t_1=0$. In this case, you can then divide by $c$ and choose a logarithm; then $\log(q_2c^{-1}) = at_2^2 + bt_3$ and $\log(q_3c^{-1}) = at_3^2+bt_3$ gives you a system of six linear equations in six unknowns that you can solve.

More accurately, $g(v) = e^{v/2}$, but that doesn't change my previous comment in any essential way.

ah okay. Seems pretty similar to what I did with the extended portion of solving the problem. That makes me think that the hack I did for calculating c is the weak link. Any suggestions for calculating c if none of the provided times equals 0. Maybe I could reframe the times such that one is zero. Say $t1$. new times would be $t1-t1, t2-t1,t3-t1$. Then once I solve it in this frame of reference I plugin $f(-t1)$ to obtain $c$ aligned with the original time. Once I do that I can then solve for $a$ and $b$ as a system of linear equations. Does that sound right?

Seems reasonable if that works for your application. This amounts to adding a constant term to the exponent: $$a(t-t_0)^2 + b(t-t_0) = at^2 + (b-2at_0)t + (at_0^2-bt_0).$$
